# JavaMelody on Railo: no SQL statistics?

Tags: java, tomcat, monitoring, railo, java-melody

I just added JavaMelody to my Railo Application server but I can't get SQL statistics.

I followed this excellent post: http://aarongreenlee.com/share/monitor-tomcat-performance-with-open-source-software

Maybe problem can be exported to other AS than Railo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the instructions here on configuring JDBC monitoring here: http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#7._JDBC

It looks like it uses a JDBC proxy if you're not using datasources in JNDI. I've recently had cause to look at how Railo does datasources and it doesn't do JNDI, so you'll probably have to set up a new datasource and follow the instructions. Do let me know whether it works.

[UPDATE] Just tried it myself. Whilst I can get the datasource working, I still get no stats. Looks like we may be running into this error:

http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/issues/detail?id=142

Comment: Not a lot I think. the way Railo makes connections doesn't lend itself to integrating JavaMelody's JDBC proxy. The 'simplest' change I can think of would be to have Railo publish its DataSources into JNDI, but that's still a change to the Railo source.